# How to get the src of the html5 picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, image

I'm trying to get the correct src of the html5 picture tag:

```
<picture>
<source media="(max-width: 575px)" srcset="/fileadmin/_processed_/7/d/csm_25675374538_e92c22790b_k_0fae925c97.jpg">
<source media="(max-width: 767px)" srcset="/fileadmin/_processed_/7/d/csm_25675374538_e92c22790b_k_b6fa9f6d7f.jpg">
<source media="(max-width: 991px)" srcset="/fileadmin/_processed_/7/d/csm_25675374538_e92c22790b_k_2c0e132222.jpg">
<source media="(max-width: 1199px)" srcset="/fileadmin/_processed_/7/d/csm_25675374538_e92c22790b_k_ad9b3a0b15.jpg">
<!-- FALLBACK -->
<img class="highlight-image" src="/fileadmin/user_upload/25675374538_e92c22790b_k.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="1280">
</picture>
```

When I try the following, than I get the path of the fallback image

```
$('img.highlight-image').attr('src')
```

But I want the src of the img which is at the screen.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy It's actually a duplicate as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const img = $('img.highlight-image');
    console.log(img[0].currentSrc); // returns the current shown image
});
```

Comment: thank you, currentSrc was the correct hint

Comment: Good I could help! Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine, but it returns a array so you can try to use

```
$('img.highlight-image').first().attr('src')
```